# Regex \w escaping in C++11

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

This code isn't returning anything, am I escaping the w character the wrong way??

http://liveworkspace.org/code/3bRWOJ$38

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    const char *reg_esp = "\w";  // List of separator characters.

// this can be done using raw string literals:
// const char *reg_esp = R"([ ,.\t\n;:])";

std::regex rgx(reg_esp); // 'regex' is an instance of the template class
                         // 'basic_regex' with argument of type 'char'.
std::cmatch match; // 'cmatch' is an instance of the template class
                   // 'match_results' with argument of type 'const char *'.
const char *target = "Unseen University - Ankh-Morpork";

// Identifies all words of 'target' separated by characters of 'reg_esp'.
if (std::regex_search(target, match, rgx)) {
    // If words separated by specified characters are present.

    const size_t n = match.size();
    for (size_t a = 0; a < n; a++) {
        std::string str (match[a].first, match[a].second);
        std::cout << str << "\n";
    }
}

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The regular expression should contain `\w`, consisting of two characters, `\` and `w`, hence your C++ source code should contain `"\\w"` as you need to escape the backslash.

Comment: @JohnnyPauling In case it keeps throwing an exception at you: You need to use a compiler and a standard library that supports `<regex>`, the above won't work with libstdc++. It does work with Clang and libc++, on my system I need to add `-stdlib=libc++` to the command line of `clang++`.

Comment: @JohnnyPauling I don't think LWS has libc++ available, it seems to use libstdc++ and hence it will always throw an exception when you try to use an regex.

Comment: Now this code works properly on LWS with clang-3.2 & libc++: http://liveworkspace.org/code/19wqrD$1

Comment: @niXman Oh, nice! (I tried it myself previously but I must have made a mistake, probably I was too hasty and tried `-stdlib=c++` or something equally embarrasing ;)

Answer (score 4):

As @DanielFrey said, for an ordinary string literal you have to double-up the backslashes. With C++11 you can use a raw string literal instead: `R"(\w)"`. The 'R' turns off handling of special characters, so the backslash is just a backslash. The parentheses mark the beginning and end of the raw string literal and are not part of the text.

Comment: You need parens too, at least; `R"(\w)"`