# How to match a string with an opening brace { in C++ regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I have about writing regexes in C++. I have 2 regexes which work fine in java. But these throws an error namely

```
 one of * + was not preceded by a valid regular expression C++
```

These regexes are as follows:

```
 regex r1("^[\s]*{[\s]*\n"); //Space followed by '{' then followed by spaces and '\n'
 regex r2("^[\s]*{[\s]*\/\/.*\n") // Space followed by '{' then by  '//' and '\n'
```

Can someone help me how to fix this error or re-write these regex in C++?

Comment: You need to escape backslashes.

Comment: I have tried both but it is still failing. I am still getting the same error

Comment: Using raw-string: `r1(R"(^[\s]*{[\s]*\n)")` may help.

Comment: Nope.It didnt work either

Comment: What is the input string that fails? What is expected behavior?

Comment: I think you need to also escape the `{` character. See https://ideone.com/rLH7Yb

Comment: I reopened the question as the [*Regex \w escaping in C++11*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998482/regex-w-escaping-in-c11) does not help answering this question. Question title is edited to reflect the real issue OP has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`basic_regex` reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/basic_regex/):

> By default, regex patterns follow the `ECMAScript syntax`.

[ECMAScript syntax reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/) states:

> **characters**:
>   `\`*character* 
>   **description**: *character*
>   **matches**: the character character as it is, without interpreting its special meaning within a regex expression.
>   Any character can be escaped except those which form any of the special character sequences above.
>   ***Needed for: `^` `$` `\` `.` `*` `+` `?` `(` `)` `[` `]` `{` `}` `|`***

So, you need to escape `{` to get the code working:

```
std::string s("\r\n  { \r\nSome text here");
regex r1(R"(^\s*\{\s*\n)");
regex r2(R"(^\s*\{\s*//.*\n)");
std::string newtext = std::regex_replace( s, r1, "" );
std::cout << newtext << std::endl;
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/rLH7Yb)

Also, note how the `R"(pattern_here_with_single_escaping_backslashes)"` raw string literal syntax simplifies a regex declaration.